# Oracle apex not recognizing user roles

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

[image]

So I have the users in a table and I know my login system works because I use it for other workspaces. However across all the applications in this particular workspace I am having an error where users roles are not being recognized in particular I can't even get the admin page to work for me and I am a developer. If anyone has any clue on how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you run the page in debug mode to check what happens ? To get as much debug information as possible change the "debug=YES" to "debug=LEVEL9"

Comment: Hey I have ran the debugger and show the results when trying to pull the admin page through developer however I can't just run the page in the application because it doesn't recognize me as an admin it also creates a different session when I go to the admin page and I'm unsure as to why

Comment: Hard to give any more tips with this little input. Pls update your question with the authorization scheme settings for the auth scheme that is failing. What is your username in the application ? How are you authenticating ? The fact that you are a developer in the workspace is not related to your role/privileges in the application.

Comment: Another remark. You state "my login system works" - that is *authentication*, the process to authenticate a user so he has access to the application. "User roles" are linked to *authorization*, the definition of what a user has access to once he is in the application. Those are 2 different concepts. From what I understand, the authorization is failing but the authentication is working fine.

Comment: Sorry Can't provide much input as the authentication scheme is under wraps it's just a different log in system still using apex roles once the user is logged in. Your Understanding is correct for every basic user but for some reason when I log in it works fine for me but not for them.

Comment: Sorry I don't think there is much I can do to help here without auth scheme details and checking the system. It'll be debugging... the api apex_authorization might be of use, also check view APEX_APPL_ACL_USER_ROLES - maybe it's something trivial

Answer (score 0):

If that first image is the default Admin pages, then wouldn't that mean you have access since you can see that page?
(which by default, if you let APEX create it for you through `New Page` > `Features` > `Access Control`) has Administration Rights set as the Authorization scheme

You have two places to check to find the issue:

1. `Shared Components` > `Security` > **Authorization** Scheme

- Go to or Click your `Administation Rights`, under `Authorization Scheme`, you need to make sure you are using `Is in Role or Group` **IF** that is the requirement and you are to use the created roles. Make sure the role, Administrator (if default roles exist) is listed.
- if validation is `once per session`, and you're still in the same session. log out and log back in. The problem should go away

2. `Shared Components` > `Security` > `Application Access Control`

- Check under Role Assignments if your username is there.
- Click Administrator under Roles, and make sure `Administration Rights` under Associated Authorization Schemes has the Is in Role or Group as the scheme type

If there is a different Authorization scheme (not Is in Role or Group) or you have different roles, then I would suggest post a new question with more details on your setup.